# is there a way to update in different field and row in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hi im kinda new to php and i've trying to do something but i cant figure it out
first of all my eng is not strong so i will try to make you guys understand

there're a table in my db that store match info like matchid and teamid

the thing i want to do is update the result of the match and then update the match that winteam and loseteam got to meet each other

like this
[image]

then when the result is updated i want it to be like this
[image]

can someone help me i cant figure it out how to do it with sql

Comment: Since we have no idea what the column names are, can't really help. More details are required.

Comment: Can you make the column needs more understandable?? It looks like you have a bunch of tables and the column names are arbitary...... We can't read it....

Comment: Can you make it English, not Arabic??

Comment: @yunfeichen this is Thai, not Arabic